# Is is possible to transform the conjunction of inequalities into one single equation?

Tags: inequality, conjunctive-normal-form, disjunctive-normal-form

I am wondering if there is a way to transform the conjunction of inequalities into one single equation.

For example, let $x_i$ be variables and $a_i$ be fixed integers. The following condition
$$(x_1 = a_1) \wedge (x_2 = a_2)\wedge \cdots \wedge (x_n = a_n) $$
can be transformed to

$$(x_1 - a_1)^2 + (x_2 -a_2)^2 + \cdots + (x_n -a_n)^2 =0. $$

Now consider the condition consisting of the conjunction of inequalities:
$$(x_1> a_1) \wedge (x_2 > a_2)\wedge \cdots \wedge (x_n > a_n) .$$

Is is possible to transform it to a single equation? Like the above example. Such a single equation should not contain $\wedge$ or $\vee$.

Edit 1:
For two-dimensions, $(x_1> a_1) \wedge (x_2 > a_2)$,we can think about the angle of between the vector $(x_1-a_1,x_2-a_2)$ and the $x_1$ axis. Can it be extended to higher dimension?

Edit 2: To make it more clear. The question is to find an analytic function $f(x_i,a_i)$. Given the input $x_1,\cdots,x_n,a_1,\cdots,a_n$, let $g = f(x_1,\cdots,x_n,a_1,\cdots,a_n)$. The condition 
$$(x_1> a_1) \wedge (x_2 > a_2)\wedge \cdots \wedge (x_n > a_n) $$
is equavalent to  "$g$ satisfies certaion conditions (e.g., $g >0$)".

Comment: You could write $\,\sum \big( (x_k - a_k) - |x_k-a_k|\big) = 0\,$, though I don't see the point.

Comment: $$\lim_{\lambda\to+\infty}\sum_k\exp\left(\lambda(a_k-x_k)\right)=0$$

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it without resorting to non-analytic functions somewhere. And I'm pretty sure everything you would consider "normal" is analytic.

In particular, there is no real analytic function $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ such that $f(x,y)>0 \iff x>0 \land y>0$.

**Proof**: By continuity, such a function would need to satisfy $f(x,0)=0$ for $x\ge 0$ and therefore by analyticity also for $x<0$. Similarly $f(0,y)=0$ for all $y$.

Now let $n$ be the smallest integer such that $\dfrac{\partial^nf}{\partial y^n}(0,x) \ne 0$ for some $x$. Because $\dfrac{\partial^nf}{\partial y^n}$ is analytic and not identically zero, it is nonzero almost everywhere -- in particular there are both postive and negative $x$ it is nonzero for.

But if $n$ is even, this means that there are positive $x$ where $f(x,y)$ have the same sign on both sides of the $x$-axis, so $\{(x,y)\mid f(x,y)>0\}$ is not the set we want.

On the other hand, if $n$ is odd, there are *negative* $x$ where $f(x,y)$ is positive on one side of the $x$-axis, again meaning that $\{(x,y)\mid f(x,y)>0\}$ is the wrong set.

Comment: The condition does not have to be $f(x,y)>0$. What we want is an analytic function f and evaluate the function value $f(x,y)$ and check if this function value meets certain conditions. For example, consider the two dimensional case $(x1>a1) \wedge (x2>a2)$. Put it on the two dimensional plane and consider the vector $(x_1-a_1,x_2-a_2)$. And then we evaluate the angle between this vector and the $x_1$ axis. And then check if this angle is within $[0,\pi/2]$.

Comment: @Paradox: How do you "evaluate the angle between this vector and the $x_1$ axis" as an analytic (and everywhere defined) operation? Also note that "check such and such is within $[0,\pi/2]$" encodes _two_ inequalities; you wanted to reduce it down to _one_.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The condition $(x_1>a_1)\wedge\cdots\wedge (x_n>a_n)$ is equivalent to
$$
\min_i \left(x_i-a_i\right) > 0.
$$

---

If the idea is to plug it into a calculator and do it approximately, you can choose a sufficiently large $m$ and just impose

$$
\left(\frac{a_1}{x_1}\right)^m + 
\cdots +
\left(\frac{a_n}{x_n}\right)^m
< 1
$$

the equivalence is **approximate** this time, but it can be made as precise as needed by increasing the number $m$. It only works when all the $a_i$ and $x_i$ are positive, or from another point of view, it approximates the condition $|x_i|>|a_i|\;\forall i$.

Comment: It is correct. But it is not what I want. I did not state it clearly in the question. But "min" is not a "normal operator" like "+,-,X,square".

Comment: @Paradox What is a normal operator, then? If they are only sums, products and powers, I don't think it is possible.

Comment: Well, I don't have a formal definition. But think about this. Suppose you have a basic calculator at hand. What I want is an equation that you can calculate with a basic calculator that supports "+,-,x,/,exp,sqrt...". The "min" function however involves comparison operation.

Comment: @Paradox With a basic calculator $((x+y)-\sqrt{x^2-2*x*y+y^2})/2$ gives the minimum of $x$ and $y$. You can easily extend this to the minimum of several numbers.